# this call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties when using 2 models in a view c# razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am having trouble using 2 models in a view in mvc.  When I try to reference the second model using razor it is giving me this error:

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Web.Mvc
.Html.DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameFor<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
<MyApp.Models.Problems>, string>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<System.Collections.
`Generic.IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Problems>`(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression
<System.Func<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Problems>,
string>>)' and 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameFor<MyApp
.Models.Problems>,string(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Systems.Collections.Generic
.IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Problems>>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func
<MyApp.Models.Problems>,string>>
```

This is how I call the model in the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Problems>
```

This is my model being loaded in the view:

```
public class Problems
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }

  public IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Category> Categories { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Type> Types {get; set;}
}
```

These are the other 2 models inside that model:

```
public partial class Category
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
}

public partial class Type
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int Order { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how I am trying to call the model inside of the problems model using razor:

```
@foreach(Problems problems in Model)
{
   foreach(Category category in problems.Categories)
   {
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(cat => @category.Title)
   }            
}
```

There error I am getting is on this line:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(cat => @category.Title)
```

Any help for me to solve this problem would be amazing, I've spent a lot of time researching and can't seem to find the proper solution.  Thank you in advance!

Edit to add controller:

So what happens is a button is clicked and I am trying to populate a modal with the razor information.

This is what I am using in the controller:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MyApp.DTOs;
using MyApp.Models;

    public class ProblemController : BaseController
        {
            private Context db = new Context();
        }
```

This is the button that kicks off the java script to create the modal I am trying to add it to(It bring in the Problem Id to the modal):

```
<button class="modal" value= @item.Id role="button">Add Problem</button>
```

Along with my javascript for the modal being created:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#myModal").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 600,
            width: 500,
            modal: true,
            open: function () {
                $("#accordion").accordion({ autoHeight: true });
            }
        });
        $(".modal").click(function () {
            defectId.value = $(this).attr('value');
            $("#myModal").dialog("open");
        })
    });
</script>
```

When The form is submitted in the modal it sends in hardcoded radio buttons values to my controller to this method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddProblem(Problems model)
{
     List<Category> c = db.Categories.ToList();
     List<Type> t = db.Types.ToList();

     return View();
}
```

This is my get method when the page is loaded:

```
public ActionResult GetProblem(ProjectProblemVM item)
        {
            var userid = getUserId();
            var userKey = getApiKey();

            // return problems
            var requestProb = new RestRequest("problem", Method.GET);
            requestProb.AddHeader("id", userid);
            requestProb.AddHeader("key", userKey);
            requestProb.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            var responseProb = Host.Execute(requestProb) as RestResponse;

            List<Problems> problems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Problems>>(responseProb.Content);
            IEnumerable<Problems> problemsToReturn = problems.Where(d => d.ProjectId == item.ProjectId);

            return View(problemsToReturn);
        }
```

Comment: Which relations are you applying for your models?

Comment: Give please the `HttpGet`

Comment: The idea would be that there would be one problem that could have many categories and many defects.  I think that is how it is set up in the Problems model at the top but I may be wrong?

Comment: Have a look on my update

Answer (score 4):

change this line:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(cat => @category.Title)
```

to

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(cat => category.Title)
```

### Update

You need also to configure well your relations one to many on all your models.

```
This is my model being loaded in the view:

public class Problems
{

  public Problems()
    {
        Categories = new List<MyApp.Models.Category>();
        Types = new List<MyApp.Models.Type>();
    }
 public int ProblemId { get; set; }
 public string Title { get; set; }

 public IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Category> Categories { get; set; }
 public IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Type> Types {get; set;}
}
```

These are the other 2 models inside that model:

```
public partial class Category
{
 public int CategoryId { get; set; }
 public string Title { get; set; }

 public virtual MyApp.Models.Problems Problem { get; set; }//Add this line to respect the one-many config
}

public partial class Type
{
public int TypeId { get; set; }
public int Order { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }

public virtual MyApp.Models.Problems Problem { get; set; }//Add this line to respect the one-many config
}
```

Source:[configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: I did that, still getting the same error.  Left the @ from all the ways I have been trying lol.

Comment: Ok, so if Problems is just a View Model that is not connected to my sql db and Category and Type are, will I run into an issue using foreign keys. Or should I just include the Problems table into my db?

Comment: Yes, if so. Just think well about the fact that you have to add the new table. But I think it will be better if you add. And regarding the `ViewModel` it wraps 2 or more classes separately. Not as you did

Comment: So I did add the foreign keys to each model as well as added it to the database.  Stil have the same error on the .cshtml page in the razor.

Comment: I have updated the constructor of Problems. I missed it. Have a look

Comment: Hmm... I added the public Problem(), still getting that crazy ambiguous error on the same line.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51386/discussion-between-lnanikian-and-shawn)